# Find nested foreach index number

Tags: knockout.js, binding

I'm trying to find index number in a nested foreach. For example, I'm trying to do this:

```html
<!-- ko foreach:array1 -->
    <!-- ko foreach:array2 -->(this index)
        <!-- ko foreach:array3 -->
            <!-- ko foreach:array4 -->
                ----( i want index of foreach array2 in here...)
            <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

I tried with `$parentContext.$index()`, with which I'm able to find array index of 1 level of nested foreach, but not more than 1 level.

Please help me to find correct binding context for the above scenario.

Comment: cant see your image can you post some code on this .

Comment: do refer the docs on binding context http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html

Comment: have you tried `$parentContext.$parentContext.$index()`

Comment: If you (think you) need this [you probably have a (view) modeling problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Also, @supercool, you should probably make that comment into an answer ;-).

Comment: @Jeroen he he tought of posting seeing you comment but no probs wayne done it :) so cool .

Comment: Great question, your question solved my problem, I was unaware how to get level 1 $index in nested array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to `wayne ellery` answer  if you want to know/compare things in a detailed way check this out .

Check [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/pf3gj0tw/1/) for working fiddle

**View :**

```
<div class="loop" data-bind="foreach: rows">
    <br/>
    <div class="nested-loop" data-bind="foreach: cells">
         <br/>
        <div class="nested-nested-loop" data-bind="foreach: candidates"> index: <span data-bind="text: $index()"></span> ||
Cell index: <span data-bind="text: $parentContext.$index()"></span>||
            Row index: <span data-bind="text: $parentContext.$parentContext.$index()"></span>
 <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will really help you to understand things better well indeed helped me once

Answer (score 1):

As Super cool mentioned above you can use `$parentContext.$parentContext.$index()`

```
<!-- ko foreach:array1 -->
    <!-- ko foreach:array2 -->
        <!-- ko foreach:array3 -->
            <!-- ko foreach:array4 -->
                <!-- ko text: $parentContext.$parentContext.$index() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9k8a7cx2/